# Laravel how to call protected function fireOtherDeviceLogoutEvent() from UserController?

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

In Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.php there is a method `fireOtherDeviceLogoutEvent($user)`.

I'd like to call it from within my UserController.

What's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can write a new function and call it in the controller.

I hope it helps you.

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\OtherDeviceLogout;
protected function fireOtherDeviceLogoutEvent()
{
    $name = Auth::getName();
    $user = Auth::user();
    event(new OtherDeviceLogout($name, $user));
}
```

Comment: I can't use logoutOtherDevices() because we don't have a user table in local database instead we use an external API for users. And as I understand logoutOtherDevices changes the password hash in user table and our external api doesn't support this.

Comment: @EmilyTuiCh
I have edited the answer, you can refer again.